# Word VBA : How to refer to a Section, without its number?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a document, on which I want to set a protection on one particular section.

I have 6 sections, the section number 5 is the one that should be protected.

I would like, later, to create a macro that would work only in section 5, the condition to enter the macro would be the following :

```
If ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Sections(1).Range.End).Sections.Count = 5 Then ...

Else: MsgBox "Not in the right section"

End If
```

However, if the user inserts a section in the document, section n°5 would become section n°6 (for a total of 7 sections) and so on.

```
Sub TestSections()




Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

Dim rngSec1 As Word.Range
Dim rngSec2 As Word.Range
Dim rngSec3 As Word.Range
Dim rngSec4 As Word.Range
Dim rngSec5 As Word.Range



Set rngSec1 = myDoc.Sections(1).Range
Set rngSec2 = myDoc.Sections(2).Range
Set rngSec3 = myDoc.Sections(3).Range
Set rngSec4 = myDoc.Sections(4).Range
Set rngSec6 = myDoc.Sections(6).Range


rngSec1.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
rngSec2.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
rngSec3.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
rngSec4.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
rngSec6.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone

myDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading

End Sub
```

In this code I protect the whole document, and give access to every section except 5.

My question: How to be able to refer to section 5 even when it is no more the section 5 ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to have something in this section that can identify it. Does it contain a specific heading text? Or graphic? It must have something special/unique...? If not, you could insert a bookmark and use that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I managed to do that using a bookmark

Comment: So you're all set, now?

Comment: Yes, this works fine

Answer (score 1):

I managed to identify my section by placing a bookmark (chose to name it "section5") at the beginning of it (Insert -> Bookmark)

Then, whenever I need to get the current number of the section I want to use, I run this code :

```
Public Sub GetBookmrkSection()

Dim bookmrk As Range
Dim bookmrk_section As String

Set bookmrk = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Section6").Range
bookmrk_section = CStr(bookmrk.Information(wdActiveEndSectionNumber))
MsgBox bookmrk_section
Set bookmrk = Nothing

End Sub
```